Inequality of inradii in triangle
I have two questions to the proof of this statement:

Let $\triangle A B C$ be a triangle with inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$ and let the interior points $D, E$ and $F$ be chosen on the sides $B C, C A$ and $A B$, respectively, so that $A D, B E, C F$ are the bisectors of the triangle $\triangle A B C$. Let $r_A, r_B, r_C$ be the inradii of the triangles $\triangle A E F, \triangle B F D, \triangle C D E$, respectively. Then
$$
r_A^2+r_B^2+r_C^2 \leq \frac{3 R^4}{64 r^2}.
$$

Proof. Let $s, s_A$ be the semiperimeters of triangles $\triangle A B C, \triangle A F E$, respectively. We have $A F=b c /(a+b)$, and $A E=b c /(a+c)$, where $a=B C, b=A C$, and $c=A B$. Comparing the areas of the triangles $\triangle A B C, \triangle A F E$ we get
$$
\frac{[\triangle A F E]}{[\triangle A B C]}=\frac{A F \cdot A E}{b c}=\frac{b c}{(a+b)(a+c)}=\color{blue}{\frac{r_A s_A}{r s}} .
$$
[...]


The author says "Comparing the areas..." and then only multiplies two of the sides. I used GeoGebra to check and the quotient of the areas are the same but why?

How does the author get $\color{blue}{\frac{r_A s_A}{r s}}?$ I found the formulas for the inradii but I cannot get to this conclusion.



For part 1, are is the product of two sides, multiplied by the angle in between, and divided by 2. Since the angle $\angle A$ is common, $$\frac{1/2 AF\cdot AE\sin\angle A}{1/2 AC\cdot AB\sin\angle A}=\frac{AF\cdot AE}{bc}$$

you already have the two sides of $\triangle AFE$ and you know the angle $\alpha$, so what's stopping you from using the theorem of cosines to find $FE$ ? then you can compute $s_A.$

For the second part say $O$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$. Then the area you can write it as the sum of the areas of the $\triangle ABO$, $\triangle BCO$, and $\triangle CAO$. So $$[\triangle ABC]=\frac12 r c+\frac12 r a+\frac12 rb=r\frac{a+b+c}2=rs$$

@Andrei I think you should post this as a solution.

The area of a triangle can be written as half of the product of two sides, multiplied by the sine of the angle between them. So for $\triangle ABC$ we have the option to express it in terms of $b$, $c$, and $\angle A$ as $$[\triangle ABC]=\frac12 b\cdot c\cdot \sin\angle A$$
Since $\triangle AFE$ shares $\angle A$ with $\triangle ABC$, we are going to write the area in terms of the adjacent sides:$$[\triangle AFE]=\frac12 AF\cdot AE\cdot \sin\angle A$$
Then you can simplify the ratio$$\frac{[\triangle AFE]}{[\triangle ABC]}=\frac{\frac12 AE\cdot AF\cdot\sin\angle A}{\frac12 b\cdot c\cdot\sin\angle A}=\frac{AE\cdot AF}{bc}$$
For the second part, use the fact that the distance (legth of the perpendicular) from the incenter to the sides is equal to the inradius. Say the incenter of $\triangle ABC$ is $O$.
Then can write the area as the sum of the areas of the $\triangle ABO$,$\triangle BCO$, and $\triangle CAO$. Therefore
$$[\triangle ABC]=[\triangle ABO]+[\triangle BCO]+[\triangle CAO]=\frac12 rc+\frac12 ra+\frac12rb=r\frac{a+b+c}2=rs$$
